# No conflict jQuery in browserify

Tags: jquery, gruntjs, private, browserify, shim

I have a large scale legacy project I am working on and I'm building some features with browserify, backbone, marionette. However, when I shim jQuery into my browserify setup, that version overwrites a different version of jQuery that was already loaded into my page before the browserify script loads up. I don't want this to happen. I need to keep that old jQuery reference separate.

Is it possible to keep my shimmed jQuery reference totally private to my browserify code? I would think I need to use jQuery's no conflict mode, but how do I do this in my grunt config setup for browserfiy.

Here's my current browserify setup in grunt.

```
        vendor: {
            src: ['www/libs/*.js'],
            dest: 'www/javascript/built/vendor.js',
            options: {
                shim: {
                    jquery: {
                        path: 'www/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
                        exports: 'jQuery'
                    },
                    underscore: {
                        path: 'www/bower_components/underscore/underscore.js',
                        exports: '_'
                    },
                    backbone: {
                        path: 'www/bower_components/backbone/backbone.js',
                        exports: 'Backbone',
                        depends: {
                            underscore: 'underscore'
                        }
                    },
                    'backbone.marionette': {
                        path: 'www/bower_components/backbone.marionette/lib/backbone.marionette.js',
                        exports: 'Marionette',
                        depends: {
                            jquery: '$',
                            backbone: 'Backbone',
                            underscore: '_'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem without using grunt or bower but I think it will probably translate.

This requires browserify-shim installed, though there may be a way to directly configure browserify to do it since it does have a configuration option for shims.

Here is my package.json:

```
// aliases for browserify
"browser": {
  "jquery": "./js/vendor/browserify-hax.js",
  // a pre-built jquery
  "static-jquery": "./js/vendor/jquery.js"
},
// tell browserify to use browserify-shim
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
// Tell browserify shim how to generate module.exports
"browserify-shim": {
  "static-jquery": {
    "exports": "$"
  }
}
```

In js/vendor/browserify-hax.js:

```
"use strict";
var jQuery = require('static-jquery');
var nonGlobal = jQuery.noConflict(true);
module.exports = nonGlobal;
```

In my application code I can use `require('jquery')` and I will get a jQuery from the bundle which is not conflicting with the existing global version.  It should be safe because the shimmed module is not actually defined until it's `require`'ed.  It's worth checking with `jQuery().jquery` that the library version is as you expect in various places anyway.

To me this feels like a very messy solution but it's the only way I could find to bundle jQuery when you already have another globally.  I'd be interested to know if you can come up with a better solution.

I also experimented with using the jQuery directly from npm but I couldn't get it to compile properly in the browserify bundle though it worked fine when using require directly in node.js.  I stuck with a pre-built jquery committed into git.